# AppHarbor self-hosted WebAPI using background worker

Tags: appharbor

Do you know if it's possible to self host an WebAPI service on an AppHarbor background worker?

Thanks

Comment: probably not since their support thread related to this topic has been closed long ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible, I'm afraid. That's because there's no way for background workers to accept incoming HTTP requests or network connections.